# Mongodb find and insert strange behavior after JSON.parse from redis?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, redis

Here is what I did , let's suppose this document

```
{
  msg:'a'
}
```

I stringify it with JSON.stringify and then save it to redis. Later I retrieve it from redis and JSON.parse and then save to mongodb in usual way.

But later when I try to retrieve the document using find({msg:'a'}) I get an empty Array.

This behavior only happens when I save the data retrieved from redis, If save it without first saving it to redis , it works fine.

What could be the problem ? I think redis is inserting some non-printable characters which I have to remove or something

Comment: How did you insert it into your redis database? what is the output of `JSON.parse`? Did you reboot your system between the two operations?

Comment: `val = JSON.stringify({msg:'a'})` , `redis.rpush(key,val)` output is 

{
  msg:'a'
}
I have tried find({}) in mongodb , the data is there , but when I copy the data from mongodb result and keep it in query in find , that doesn't work.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.